# Why my selected button Image is disappear back to default image when I Scrolling Horizontal Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am setting a selected button Image when when I tap bookmarkbuttob call addbookmark api inside the custom collectionView Cell. But when I scrolling horizontally it changes back to empty heart image from filled heart image. Give me an easy way to solve this with code example.

Check my codes below

TableViewCell

API Call

```
    func getRecipeWeekly(url: String){
            switch isLogin {
            case true:
                self.headers = [
                   "Authorization": "Token \(token ?? "")",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                ]
            default:
                self.headers = [
                //    "Authorization": "Token \(token ?? "")",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                ]
            }
        
            AF.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                
                switch response.result {
                    
                case let .success(value):
                    //   self.isLogin = true
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print("Original weekly Recipe Responce: \(json)")
                    self.recipes.removeAll()
                    if let rcpArray = json.array{
                        if !rcpArray.isEmpty || rcpArray != [] {
                            for rcpJSON in rcpArray {
                                let recipe = Recipe.parseRecipe(rcpJSON: rcpJSON)
                                self.recipes.append(recipe)
                              //  self.bookMarkDic[String(recipe.pk ?? 0)] = recipe.isFav
                              //  UserDefaults.standard.set(self.bookMarkDic, forKey: "kBookMarkDic")
                            }
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    }
                case let .failure(error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }


 extension RecipesHolderCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.recipes.count
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RecipeStackCell", for: indexPath)
                as! RecipeStackCell
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let rcp = self.recipes[indexPath.row]
                //fetching bookmark dict
                
                
                
                cell.rcpID = rcp.pk
                cell.isFav = rcp.isFavourite ?? false
                cell.indexPosition = indexPath.row
                
               switch cell.isFav{
                case true:
                    cell.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "new_heart_white"), for: .normal)
                    cell.buttonActive = true
                default:
                    cell.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart_normal"), for: .normal)
                    cell.buttonActive = false
                }
                cell.rcpImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                let rcpTitle = rcp.title?.stripOutHtml()
                cell.rcpNameLabel.text = rcpTitle
                cell.cookTimeLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
                .normalLeft("Cook time ")
                .boldLeft("\(String(rcp.cookTime ?? 0)) Mins")
               // cell.rcpNameLabel.sizeToFit()
    
                // fetching image
                self.imageUrl = rcp.imageUrl
                let escapedUrl = self.imageUrl?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
                let replacedUrl = "\(escapedUrl!)"
                self.rcpUrl = "\(replacedUrl)"
                let url = URL(string: self.rcpUrl ?? "")
                cell.rcpImageView.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.transition(.fade(0.3))])
            }
            return cell
        }
```

CustomCell

```
@IBAction func bookMarkBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if isLogin == false
        {
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "executeLoginAlert"), object: nil)
        }
        else
        {

        if buttonActive {
         
            self.removeBookmark()
            }
            else {
          
            self.addBookMark()
            }
          
            buttonActive = !buttonActive
        }
    }
    
    func addBookMark(){
         
                let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                    "Authorization": "Token \(token ?? "")",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                ]
                
                let param : [String : AnyObject] = ["id": self.rcpID ?? 0] as [String : AnyObject]
                print("sent qty: \(param)")
                
                //  param = ["username":self.emailTextField.text ?? "", "password": self.passwordText.text as // AnyObject] as [String : AnyObject]
                
            AF.request("\(choithrams_live.url)recipes/favourites/add/\(self.rcpID ?? 0)/", method: .post, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200..<299).responseJSON { response in
                    
                    switch response.result {
                     
                    case let .success(value):
                        //   self.isLogin = true
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print("add to basket Responce: \(json)")
                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue("Successfully Added to the saved recipes!", forKey: "kCellAlertMessage")
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "cellAlertPassed"), object: nil)
                        self.isFav = true
                     //   UserDefaults.standard.setValue(self.indexPosition, forKey: "kIndxPosition")
                    //    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "recipeBookMarkPassed"), object: nil)
                        self.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "new_heart_white"), for: .normal)
                        // refresh cart items and batch count
                        // self.updateCartItems()
                        
                    case let .failure(error):
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                        self.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart_normal"), for: .normal)
                    }
                }
            }
        
        func removeBookmark(){
            
                   let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                       "Authorization": "Token \(token ?? "")",
                       "Accept": "application/json"
                   ]
                   
                   let param : [String : AnyObject] = ["id": self.rcpID ?? 0] as [String : AnyObject]
                   print("sent qty: \(param)")
                   
                   //  param = ["username":self.emailTextField.text ?? "", "password": self.passwordText.text as // AnyObject] as [String : AnyObject]
                   
               AF.request("\(choithrams_live.url)recipes/favourites/remove/\(self.rcpID ?? 0)/", method: .delete, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200..<299).responseJSON { response in
                       
                       switch response.result {
                           
                       case let .success(value):
                           //   self.isLogin = true
                           let json = JSON(value)
                           print("remove bookmark Responce: \(json)")
                           UserDefaults.standard.setValue("Removed from saved rcipes!", forKey: "kCellAlertMessage")
                         //  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "cellAlertPassed"), object: nil)
                       //    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "recipeBookMarkPassed"), object: nil)
                           self.isFav = false
                           self.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart_normal"), for: .normal)
                           
                       case let .failure(error):
                           print("Error: \(error)")
                           self.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "new_heart_white"), for: .normal)
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Comment: After tapping on a bookmark, you also need to update your self.recipes array after received success response.

Comment: I know that but my collectionView is reloading and indexposition is moving around and solutions.

Comment: No need to reloading the full collection view just update your object manually.